# jQuery menu and dropdown, how to add active state and keep it while reloading page?

Tags: jquery, menu, dropdown

I have the following jQuery code

```
/***********************************************/
 /* PAGES : ADD ACTIVE SIDEBAR MENU CLASS */
 /***********************************************/
 

 var url = window.location;
 $('#menuList li a').filter(function() {
  return this.href == url;
}).attr('aria-current','page').parent().addClass('activeMenuItem');
/***********************************************/
/* PAGES : DROPDOWN MENU */
/***********************************************/

$('#menuList li a').click(function(){      
 
$('#menuList li a').removeAttr('aria-current','page').parent().removeClass('activeMenuItem');
  $(this).attr('aria-current','page').addClass('activeMenuItem');
  if($(this).next('ul').length>0){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#menuList li a ul').removeClass('activated');
    $('#menuList li a').attr('aria-expanded',false);
     $(this).attr('aria-expanded',true);
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  }
   });
```

First one is to add active state on first level ul >li>a on load and when changing pages.
second one is to open dropdown menu when clickin on a ul>li>a that have a dropdown menu.

How can I shorten and mix these two pieces of code, in order to always have the current menu item "active"
whatever level it is, open the dropdown menu and keep it open while changing pages..
I first thought building tab for the submenu, that would allow me maybe to avoid "reloading page"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I found a solution, but still think that it could be improved..any help would be appreciated !! Here is my working code..

```
 /***********************************************/
 /* PAGES : ADD ACTIVE SIDEBAR MENU CLASS on LOAD */
 /***********************************************/
 var url = window.location;//if the page path (main menu) meet the page url
 $('#menuList li a').filter(function() {//add aria and active state to mainmenu li a on load
  return this.href == url;
}).attr('aria-current','page').parent().addClass('activeMenuItem');

 $('#menuList ul li a').filter(function() {//if the page path(dropdown) meet the page url
  return this.href == url;//add aria and active state to dorpdown li a on load
}).attr('aria-current','page').parent().parent().addClass('activated');
 /***********************************************/
 /* PAGES : DROPDOWN MENU */
 /***********************************************/

 $('#menuList li a').click(function(){      //if click on menu link
   $('#menuList li').removeClass('activeMenuItem');//remove active state from all links

   if($(this).next('ul').length > 0){//if there is a dropdown in the menu item
    event.preventDefault();//prevent from following the link
    $('#menuList li').removeClass('activeMenuItem'); //remove active state
    $('#menuList li a').attr('aria-expanded',false);//aria expanded false to all dropdown li
    $('#menuList ul').removeClass('activated');//hide dropdown
    $(this).attr('aria-expanded',true);//add aria expanded true to this dropdown
    $(this).next().slideToggle();//show the dropdown
    $(this).parent().addClass('activeMenuItem');//add active state to this menu item
  }

});
```